# Why do I get 'Instance member '___' cannot be used on type '___' in prepareForSegue?

Tags: swift3, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass data from one view controller to another using this method:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if segue.identifier == "toSecondViewController" {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

            SecondViewController.username = "Austin"
        }

    }
```

However, I'm getting the error

> Instance member 'username' cannot be used on type
>   'SecondViewController'

the variable `username` has been defined in `SecondViewController` and the segue is indeed named `toSecondViewController`. What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me all the time.

```
if segue.identifier == "toSecondViewController" {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

            SecondViewController.username = "Austin"
        }
```

Notice how `SecondViewController.username = "Austin"` has a capital S.. it should be lower case.

You declare a variable `let secondViewController as! SecondViewController`
but then you try to set .userName on SecondViewController, capital S

You should set .userName on the variable `secondViewController`.  Lowercase s, which is what you intended.

Comment: Martin.. the segue is happening now without any errors, but it doesn't seem like the data is being passed through to SecondViewController. Is there an easy way I can test it?

Comment: In secondViewController, show me how you declare username.  
var username = What did you declare here?

You might have declared let, which means you can't change it.

Comment: In SecondViewController I declared var username = “”

Comment: How are you testing that data hasn't been passed? What happens if "Austin" is passed?

Comment: I'm calling `print(username)` in viewDidLoad of SecondViewController. I've also tried calling in viewDidAppear. It prints blank instead of printing "Austin"

Comment: I'm sorry, Austin.  I can't figure it.  Sorry.

Comment: I got it.   prepareForSegue() is never being called.  put a print statement in there.

Comment: MARTIN, YOU'RE THE MAN. I found out I was using prepareForSegue() but it was requiring me to use prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) for some reason. Once I reformatted the method like that it worked! Thanks again.